# Search Engine for 3D Models

Tags: webapp-rec, search, search-engine, 3d

I want to use Google SketchUp to design my rooms. Where can I find 3D Models to fill up the empty space in my designed rooms?

Bonus points to search for similar looking 3D Models, based upon existing models I have already on my box (have a look at the [victory-project](http://www.victory-eu.org:8080/victory/results/search.html) and [princeton](http://shape.cs.princeton.edu/search.html) to get an idea of what I am looking for)

I do not want "3D search" as in "We just display ordinary search results in a 3D-ish way and call this 3D search", such as [kickfly.com](http://search.kickfly.com) and the likes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has such a search engine called [3D Warehouse.](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/)

Comment: This is what I have always used.  Many times I even find what I am looking for by Model Number.  If it is IKEA furniture I can always find it by name.  A really great tool when you are trying to layout a room.  If you can't find exactly what you are looking for you can usually use the scale tool to resize a generic item to match the one you are trying to represent (I've done this for couches many times.)

Answer (score 1):

[3DFilter](http://3dfilter.com) looks like a nice webapp as well.